# Is a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ also a basis of every subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if I have 5 five-dimensional vectors and their span is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^5$, will any basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ be a basis of the span, too?

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: The fact that, as @user137500 said, a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ would still span the subspace.

Comment: They wouldn't even *be* in the subspace! The first words of the definition of a basis are (for example) "Vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ **in $V$** are a basis of $V$ if..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the five vectors are linearly independent then yes (in this case there span *is* $\mathbb{R}^5$).

If not, then no. Because then the dimension of the space will be $<5$, so the span cannot contain $5$ linearly independent vectors.

However, if the span has dimension $k<5$ and $k$ of the vectors in the basis lie in the span, then these $k$ vectors *will* form a basis for the span.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, the vector $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ spans a one-dimensional subspace of R5. While any basis of R5 would certainly *span* that subspace, it would be linearly dependent, and hence not a basis. Because the subspace is one-dimensional, any basis must consist of exactly one vector.

EDIT: Actually, any basis would span the subspace + more. It would not really be linearly dependent or independent, as four of its vectors (or five) would not even be in the subspace at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the subset is not all of $\mathbb R^5$, then it cannot possibly contain a basis for $\mathbb R^5$, so that basis cannot be a basis for the subspace.